# ein failed to login to 8888

Tags: python, emacsclient, ipython, ein

I was using emacs-ipython-notebook for data visualisation for some days.But then I started getting the error -**ein failed to login to 8888**.I checked my ipyhton notebook server and it's running on default port 8888 and I also tried to change the port number and login again but failed.I tried **ein:dev-bug-report-template** and here goes my system info

````
## System info:

```cl
("EIN system info"
 :emacs-version
 "GNU Emacs 24.3.1 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, GTK+ Version 3.10.7)
 of 2014-03-07 on lamiak, modified by Debian"
 :emacs-bzr-version nil
 :window-system x
 :emacs-variant nil
 :os
 (:uname
  "Linux jamesbondu-HP-Pavilion-g6-Notebook-PC 4.2.0-41-generic #48~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jun 24 17:09:15 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
"
  :lsb-release
  "No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS
Release:    14.04
Codename:   trusty
")
 :image-types
 (svg imagemagick png gif tiff jpeg xpm xbm pbm postscript)
 :image-types-available
 (svg imagemagick png gif tiff jpeg xpm xbm pbm postscript)
 :request
 (:backend curl)
 :ein
 (:version "0.12.1"
       :source-dir "/home/jamesbondu/.emacs.d/elpa/ein-20170119.927/")
 :lib
 ((:name "websocket"
     :path "~/.emacs.d/elpa/websocket-20161113.1736/websocket.elc"
     :featurep t
     :version-var websocket-version
     :version "1.5")
  (:name "request"
     :path "~/.emacs.d/elpa/request-20161221.1711/request.elc"
     :featurep t
     :version-var request-version
     :version "0.2.0")
  (:name "popup"
     :path "~/.emacs.d/elpa/popup-20160709.729/popup.el"
     :featurep nil
     :version-var nil
     :version nil)
  (:name "python"
     :path "/usr/share/emacs/24.3/lisp/progmodes/python.elc"
     :featurep t
     :version-var nil
     :version nil)))
```
````

Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> "GNU Emacs 24.3.1 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, GTK+ Version 3.10.7)
> ```

EIN only works on Emacs 25. See https://github.com/millejoh/emacs-ipython-notebook/issues/190.

If perchance you use a Ubuntu derivative, there is a ppa:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:kelleyk/emacs
```

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this problem and found that the issue was with the token that jupyter notebooks now use. I disabled the token per this [GitHub issue](https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/2254). I'm reproducing the instructions below:

```
cd ~/.jupyter
jupyter notebook --generate-config

Then set the c.NotebookApp.token parameter to an empty string 

c.NotebookApp.token = ''
```

Note that if you care about security, this is not recommended. Instead you should be able to enter the token into EIN.

Answer (score 0):

I was experimenting similar issues and it was solved by step three in EIN guide to solve problems. Have you tried it?

```
[  ] I read "Avoid standard Emacs traps" section in
https://github.com/tkf/emacs-ipython-notebook/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md
[  ] I checked that IPython works with the browser interface.
[  ] I checked that the problem was not due to badly compiled
files. Removing *.elc files from source directory of EIN and
its dependencies did not solve the problem.
[  ] I checked that the libraries are loaded from intended place.
(You can check the location in the "System info" section below)
```